# php simple xml file gives timeout but site is fine

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I am having a weird problem... I use simpleXML_load_file to parse a news site. It worked fine until yesterday, now, for some reason it gives timeout, but the site is fine(you can navigate to it through a browser.

I have the same code in several servers and none of them is working.

Could it be that the site I parse make some change?

Comment: do you have any reason to beleave that the side didn't change ? Do you use `$simplexml->strictErrorChecking = false;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wrapper of curl to retrieve the result first, and then load to simpleXML. This will allow you to write in retries a little better than doing retries on simpleXML_load_file.

It's not likely, but they could have blocked requests from certain client types (CURL) from your IP or all.

Comment: Self promotion: https://github.com/WolfeDev/Curl & https://github.com/WolfeDev/PageScraper - These are first runs and not complete.